# How to Get the Clients printer device list in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a web application with custom printing using asp.net mvc.

After it is hosted, I want a user to be able to get the client's printer device list. Is it possible to get the client's printer devices names?

Comment: What browser are your clients using?

Comment: This may have been possible on older versions of windows and IE in the past with activex but isn't possible now. Accessing the OS from the browser is a security concern.

Comment: For obvious security reasons, you cannot access a client's printers (or any devices)